# Leer archivo diréctamente del disco sin la memoria caché en bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cache

Estoy creando un script en bash con ubuntu y necesito saber si es posible deshabilitar el caché para un determinado archivo o dispositivo (/dev/xxx).

Básicamente lo que intento hacer es calcular los sha256 de un directorio o dispositivo y volver a calcular los de otro. Los sha256 deberían ser iguales si no han sido modificados.

¿El caché podría afectar al resultado de esta comparación o igualmente se vuelve a leer?

UPDATE:

Encontré lo siguiente:

```
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Lo he probado con sudo y no me funciona. Sólo funciona con su, por lo tanto no me es útil.

¿Hay algún comando más específico sólo para lo que se ejecuta dentro de bash?

Comment: Y, aparte de que posiblemente tu *script* tarde mas tiempo en ejecutarse, ¿ Que problema tienes o que objetivo esperas conseguir con eso ?

Comment: En realidad, antes de hacer esta pregunta, me preguntaba si no era demasiado tonta. Que mi script tarde demasiado tiempo no sería un problema mientras que consiga el objetivo de leer los datos del disco tal cual están en ese momento.
No sé si estoy en lo correcto, pero me temo que el caché pueda ser usado al leer el disco y que la diferencia de algún byte que se produzca en el disco no sea detectada. No estoy tan seguro cómo funciona el caché y si podría hacer esto; por eso mi duda.

Comment: No sé si te servirá. Para un proyecto de seguridad, evitar modificación en binarios, utilicé hace tiempo Tripwire.  Saca el hash de todo lo que quieras de tus discos una vez, lo mete en su bbdd  y luego  cuando se vuelve a ejecutar, compara lo actual con lo anterior y   te avisa si se ha cambiado alguno. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripwire

Comment: El Sistema Operativo se encarga de que el disco y la caché sean consistentes, en otro caso sería divertido el comportamiento de los programas. Y, aunque desactivaras la caché, ¿ Que garantía tienes de que el archivo no se modifique 1 segundo después de que tú lo leas ? Y esto puede ocurrir siempre. No le veo el sentido a lo que quieres hacer, la verdad.

Comment: @Trauma No me había dado cuenta que era el mismo que respondió en la otra pregunta xD. Supongo que de ser así, entonces no debería preocuparme. Voy a ver si primero cumple mi objetivo y después evaluaré qué hacer con este problema. Estaba pensando en bloquear la carpeta pero no estoy seguro si se puede, y si se puede, seguro hacen falta permisos de root. ¡Muchas gracias por todo!